# Print the location or filename of an uploaded file from a custom content type

Tags: 8, files

I'm trying to figure out how to print out the file path and the name of the file uploaded from a custom content type. I have my template all setup and everything printing how I need to, the last thing is I just need to be able to print out the path or at least the name of the file from the upload attached to the content.

I tried using:

```
{{ node.field_name.value }}
{{ node.field_name.url }}
{{ node.field_name.content }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file field is an entity reference field, you can get the first file entity with `.entity`:

```
{{ node.field_downloads.entity.filename.value }}
{{ node.field_downloads.entity.uri.value }}
```

And access the fields of the file entity as usually.

If you have more than one file in the field:

```
second file:
{{ node.field_downloads.1.entity.filename.value }}
third file:
{{ node.field_downloads.2.entity.filename.value }}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me yesterday too, I figured out a lot but this was one of the last things I couldn't seem to find